# How to add route group inside another route group.. Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, routes

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router){

});

Route::group([

  'prefix' => 'api/v1',
  'namespace' => 'Api'

], function () {

    Route::post('/auth/register', [
    'as' => 'auth.register',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@register'
  ]);

  Route::post('/auth/login', [

    'as' => 'auth.login',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@login'
  ]);

});
```

I want to add the prefix group route inside the middleware route, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can nest route groups inside of each other. Just wrap one in the closure of the other.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router){
    Route::group(
        [
          'prefix' => 'api/v1',
          'namespace' => 'Api'
        ], function () {
            Route::post('/auth/register', [
                'as' => 'auth.register',
                'uses' => 'AuthController@register'
             ]);

            Route::post('/auth/login', [
                'as' => 'auth.login',
                'uses' => 'AuthController@login'
            ]);
    });
});
```

Comment: See my comments on your post below. I think your problems are unrelated to route grouping. Also I knew that you could simply add the CORS middleware to your array and keep it to one route group, but since you specifically asked about putting route groups *inside* each other, I answered it like this.

Answer (score 0):

hey i solved this by,

```
Route::group([

  'prefix' => 'api/v1',
  'namespace' => 'Api',
   'middleware'  =>'cors'

],
 function () {

    Route::post('/auth/register', [
    'as' => 'auth.register',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@register'


  ]);
  Route::post('/auth/login', [

    'as' => 'auth.login',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@login'

  ]);
```

});

but the problem here is i am getting this error 
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.**

is there any problem with my chrome cause i heard there is plugin for cors in chrome.

Thanks :)

Comment: This is a CORS error which *could* indicate a problem with your CORS middleware; HOWEVER, because you are getting a status code of 500 it likely means that something is wrong with your Auth controller. If you don't use the CORS middleware does it work? If so, investigate the middleware. If it still breaks then it is a problem with your Auth implementation. Maybe it is not getting all the data passed correctly to it?

Comment: Thanks Andy you were right i was entering the wrong user name and password may be that was the reason. right?

Comment: Well hopefully your authentication would handle an incorrect username/password in a better way than to break with a 500 error, so it is probably something else. If you take out the CORS middleware, does it work, or at least not break? If your CORS middleware is causing the issue, keep in mind that it might not be broken but simply not configured correctly. I once spent a long time confused why my own CORS middleware wasn't working until I realized I hadn't correctly configured the allowed origins.

Comment: If you are trying to log in with AJAX and using the built-in AuthController, you might have some troubles. I did the same thing and had to build my own custom AuthController because my database didn't have things like the `remember_me` token. You're really going to have to try each piece by itself and see if you can identify which part is your problem.

Comment: Well i am new to these technologies and spent nearly a month along with these two ,sometimes it get so frustating and there are few more like yeoman and grunt so yes there is long way to go.

Comment: Yes, that's always the struggle of learning a new technology but eventually things always fall into place :) Like I said before, you need to break this down piece by piece to see what's wrong. I would suggest trying your authentication *without* going through AJAX. Instead use some blade views (if you're on Laravel 5.2 you can run `php artisan make:auth` to make some) and see if you're able to log in with those. If that works, then you know it's a problem with the request. And just keep trying to break things down into their simplest form until you find the problem.